# Html Put everything horizontally

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm using data tables to show the data I have ... my problem is that if a name or an input field is too large ... in my case, the action buttons, instead of always being horizontal. .. they stand vertically, always descending a line. My objective is for this to fit and fit horizontally ... I will show the problem described in the image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymgku.png)

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="table_id" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID_Cliente
            </th>
            <th>
                Nome
            </th>
            <th>
                Morada
            </th>
            <th>
                Telemóvel
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Ações
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Cliente)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Morada)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telemovel)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Edit","Clientes",new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sx btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Details","Clientes", new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sx btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Detalhes</a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Delete","Clientes", new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sx btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

**CSS**

```
min-height: 1000px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px

.dataTables_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1;
```

Comment: cannot find the image

Comment: @DhananjaiPai and now?

Comment: Your CSS looks imcomplete.  Please provide a minimal, verifiable, complete, example.  If you could create a runnable snippet, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, there is no problem if the other columns break, but it is important to the last one, with the actions buttons to stay always horizontal, is it correct?

if yes, maybe the below flex CSS can help you. Please check it.
If not helps, please, desconsider my answer.

(to reproduce an example, i made some modifications in the HTML part)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable();
        });
```

```css
.buttons{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

a.btn{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="table_id" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID_Cliente
            </th>
            <th>
                Nome
            </th>
            <th>
                Morada
            </th>
            <th>
                Telemóvel
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Ações
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>        
            <tr>
                <td>
                    item.ID_Cliente
                </td>
                <td>
                    item.Nome
                </td>
                <td>
                    item.Morada
                </td>
                <td>
                    item.Telemovel 9999999999999
                </td>
                <td>
                    item.Email aaaaaaaaaaada@aaaaaa
                </td>
                <td class="buttons">
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Edit","Clientes",new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sx btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Details","Clientes", new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sx btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Detalhes</a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Delete","Clientes", new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sx btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always set fixed widths to each of the  with css. You can use overflow-wrap property (read here : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/ ) to wrap text or set `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow:ellipsis`

Make sure that the last td has enough width to fit your buttons hotizontally. But then again, if you are looking for a responsive designs, I must say, the buttons take up a lot of space!

Comment: therefore, I would like the horizontal expansion to be done automatically ... that is, everything adapts itself.

You're right, the buttons take up a lot and if you can not find the solution, I'll have to think about something else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Bootstrap, right?

Why not try small buttons?

Instead `btn-sx` try `btn-sm`.
Also, you can use a button group too.

Check my Pen with an example: https://codepen.io/vicainelli/pen/jpGJbK

Comment: Yes, I'm using bootstrap.
Thanks for sharing!